# Problema con objeto en Nsarray

Tags: swift, xcode

Lo que quiero realizar es solo agarrar el `idCategoria` del objeto para poder utilizarlo en otra consulta pero marca el siguiente error:

> cannot convert value of string to expected argument to int

```
let objeto = values["idCategoria"]
print(objeto)`
```

Codigo completo

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
//var identificador = ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]

var values:NSArray = []


//var arr =  ["http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/IOs/categorias.php"]

//let colors = [UIColor.brownColor(),UIColor.purpleColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.grayColor()]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let proxyViewForStatusBar : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 20))
    proxyViewForStatusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.48627450980392156, green: 0.070588235294117646, blue: 0.46274509803921571, alpha: 1)
    self.view.addSubview(proxyViewForStatusBar)


    get();
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet() as NSCharacterSet).uppercaseString

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString = cString.substringFromIndex(cString.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
    }

    if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.grayColor()
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    NSScanner(string: cString).scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}


func get(){
    let url = NSURL(string:"http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/IOs/categorias.php")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

    values = ((try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? NSArray)!

}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



    return values.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    //NSLog("La liga es %@ %@", maindata["idCategoria"] as! String, maindata["nombre"] as! String);
    cell.nombre.text = maindata["nombre"] as? String
    cell.descripcion.text = maindata["descripcion"] as? String
    //cell.idCategoria.text = maindata["idCategoria"] as? String

   let colors = [hexStringToUIColor("#FF0000"),hexStringToUIColor("#FF8000"),hexStringToUIColor("#FFFF00"),hexStringToUIColor("#80FF00"),hexStringToUIColor("00FFFF"),hexStringToUIColor("#0080FF"),hexStringToUIColor("#A901DB"),hexStringToUIColor("#FF00FF"),hexStringToUIColor("#FF0080")]

    cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
    cell.imagen.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row % colors.count]





    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



    let objeto = values["idCategoria"]
    print(objeto)

}

}
```

Comment: ¿Donde le asignas los valores a `values[]`? anexa tu código más completo asi obtendras mejor ayuda y evitas que sea cerrada tu pregunta

Comment: Listo, acabo de agregar el código completo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values` es un array de `JSON` y por tanto primero debes coger el objeto y después acceder a su propiedad, es decir:

```
let objeto = values[indexPath.row]["idCategoria"]
print(objeto)
```

Comment: Creo que era muy fácil, soy muy nuevo en esto de IOs y otra pregunta después de acceder a esa propiedad quiero mandarla a otro vista que dependiendo el id muestra las subcategorias, ¿se puede hacer eso?

Comment: Claro, la forma más correcta sería enviar todo el objeto `JSON` para tener toda la info. Crea un propiedad en la vista de destino llamada `mainData` por ejemplo. Una vez la instancias para mostrarla, pásala a la siguiente vista

Comment: Eso si más o menos lo se, solo quiero pasar el id para que en la siguiente vista la utilice en un url para mostrar las subcategorias correspondientes

Comment: Pues haz lo mismo, pero con un tipo `Int` y listo. Una vez lo tengas en la otra vista, en el `viewWillAppear` utilizado para cargar los datos que sean necesarios